# How to get all values in a column in table using vaadin SQLContainer

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Hi Stackoverflow members,

I have one SQLContainer with TableQuery. Now, I want to get all the values in one column. How can I get it? Or Shall I need to go with FreefromQuery?

This is my SQLContainer code

```
public SQLContainer getMyContainer() {
    //FreeformQuery query = null;
    SQLContainer container = null;
    try {

             connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                    "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vaadin", "root", "root",
                    2, 5);
             TableQuery query = new TableQuery("components", connectionPool);
            /*query = new FreeformQuery(
                    "SELECT rowNum, colNum, caption, cType FROM items where screenId='"
                            + screenName+"'", connectionPool);
            query.setDelegate(new DemoFreeformQueryDelegate());*/
            container = new SQLContainer(query);

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return container;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you wish to do.

With SQLContainer you could do it this way:

```
// Returns a list with all ID's (Beware of large resultsets)
Collection<?> itemIDS= conatiner.getItemIds();
for (Object itemID : itemIDS)
{
     Property property= container.getContainerProperty(itemID, "COLUMN");
     Object data= property.getValue();
}
```

The getItemIds() must fetch all rows from the DB (at least the primary keys),
so this will cause troubles with large resultsets/tables.

https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/sqlcontainer/SQLContainer.html#getItemIds%28%29

Comment: Actually I want to restrict user not to enter the existed values specified column. But `getItemIds()` will cause problems. I want to know is there any alternative?

Comment: Isn't there a better way than that? If I want to get all the values as a Collection<?>, I have to create an ArrayList<Object>, fill it with the data objects and return it as a Collection<?>